# SwiftUI .sheet crash

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I encountered a problem when using `.sheet`. The application crashes with the message **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

```
@main
struct No_EmotionApp: App {
    
    @State private var showing_add = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("")
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showing_add) {
                    
                } content: {
                    Text("")
                }
                .onAppear{
                    self.showing_add.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use .sheet and run it through toogle to reproduce the error - the application doesn't open the modal window and crashes right away

Steps took to reproduce the issue:

1. add .sheet to App
2. toogle Bool
3. wait for crash

FB9732500 — Developer Tools

Comment: Works for me - Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233), iPhone 11 Pro

Comment: xcode version 13.1

Comment: I copied and pasted this code into a new project, using Xcode 13.1, and it compiled and ran without trouble in the simulator.  Are you running in simulator, or on device?  Which iOS (for the simulator or device)?

Comment: IOS 15.0, I'm testing on simulator and phone - both have the same behavior. @ScottThompson

Comment: Seems like it's working fine. How about you try quitting Xcode, clean `DerivedData` folder of Xcode, clean build folder too and then try running it again?

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the project was the added AccentColor in the Assets section.  The color was selected from a list - tintColor in the tvOS section - the project was purely for IOS.

Xcode only issued a warning:

AccentColor references a system color named tintColor for platform tvOS, but the catalog is building for iOS. The color may appear differently at runtime.

The whole project ran except for the .sheet! I changed the color and everything worked.

Comment: If it's crashing from a completely different reason than what you stated on the question, you should remove the question altogether.